# C# - show error window instead of interruption by exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql

So I am trying to enclose these 2 queries into `try - catch` so if the username/password don't exist then the exception is caught and only an error message window is shown, instead of breaking the whole application:

```
try
{
   command.CommandText = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "'";
   reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   reader.Read();
   string myUsername = reader.GetString(0);
   values[0] = myUsername;

   command.CommandText = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "'";
   reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   reader.Read();
   string myPassword = reader.GetString(0);
   values[1] = myPassword;
}
catch (Exception)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password!");
}
```

I know the logic of checking for the correct username and it's particular password is not correct but I am gonna fix that later. I now want just to know how to show the message instead of breaking the whole process.

Comment: what problem u having with current code

Comment: is it not working...i thought it shuld work

Comment: At the moment you are using username for the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your actual question, putting code inside a `try catch` block will do as you want it to, which is to say it will catch the error and execute the code block inside the `catch`.

I expect that your confusion lies in that when running code in Visual Studio's Debug mode the debugger will stop on the error anyway to highlight the error to you. This won't happen when you run the code from an executable.

To get your program to run through your code without stopping for errors (I'm not saying this is a good idea by the way)

- Click on the "Debug" menu at the top of Visual Studio
- Select "Exceptions"
- Uncheck the "user-handled" "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkbox.

That should suppress the error to mimic running from an executable and you should see your message box.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't embed text directly into your SQL command, you'll open yourself up to SQL injection attacks.
Secondly, you probably don't need two queries; the first one is really just checking for the existence of the username.  Use something like

```
select password from users where username = @username
```

(and use a parameter to provide the username)

Then, rather than relying on an exception to catch the bad login, check the result of the `Read()` call; false should indicate no rows (and hence no matching username / password combination).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can show the exception message by changing the catch to this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("The Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
}
```

However, you might not want to show the raw message.  I would recommend to show a message that is under your control:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // log the exception
   // Logger.Log(ex);

   MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find username: " + username);
}
```

Side note: [use parameterized queries!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)